# Как сделать, чтобы функция возвращала 2 и более значений?

Tags: функции, delphi

Как сделать, чтобы функция возвращала 2 и более значений?

Знаю, что это можно сделать как-то через `out`, но не знаю как.

Comment: Возвращайте массив этих значений...

Comment: В нормальных языках программирования создается класс с нужными полями/свойствами и возвращается объект этого класса. Как в Delphi не знаю.

Comment: >  В нормальных языках программирования  

радуют меня подобные высказывания по отношению к делфям)

Comment: @teanЫЧ, что в Delphi нет классов? Способ решения я написал, пусть пишет реализацию сам. З.Ы. Без Холиваров не могу. :)

Comment: @Olter, есть :)  

З.Ы. Холивары наше всё

Comment: Можно создать даже не класс, а запись(Record). Погуглите по этому поводу...

Answer (score 6):

Вот тут полистайте, вроде бы доходчиво описано [Параметры процедур и функций](http://helpapi.narod.ru/OsnovDelphi/040.htm) .

Answer (score 3):

**TRecord** Вам в помощь

Объявляете сначала тип , а функция возвращает этот тип, может и не 2 а не ограниченное количество возвращать.

[Ключевое слово Record](http://delphibasics.ru/Record.php)

Answer (score 2):

Я бы скорее всего создал бы новый тип данных( что в общем-то верно ), который бы было удобно эксплуатировать при возврате значения функцией. Но так как я "не знаком" с вашей задачей, то предложу использовать тип данных TList. Это, по сути, динамическая структура данных. Пример:

```
function func():TList;
var list:TList;
i:integer;
begin
list:=TList.Create;
for i:=0 to 5 do list.Add(Pointer(i));
func:=list;
end;

...
var list:TList;
i,a:integer;
...
list:=TList.Create;
list.Assign(func());
for i:=0 to list.Count-1 do
begin
a:=Integer(list[i]);
ShowMessage(IntTostr(a));
end;
...
```

**UPD**  Если заморачиваться с TList не особо хочется, то можно попробовать юзать обычные динамические массивы( правда тут уже надо определяться с типом данных ):

```
...
type
DynArray=array of integer;
...
const N=4;

function func(n:integer = N):DynArray;
var list:DynArray;
i:integer;
begin
SetLength(list,n);
for i := 0 to n do list[i]:=random(10);
Result:=list;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var list:DynArray;
i:integer;
begin
SetLength(list,N);
list := func(N);
for i:=0 to N-1 do ShowMessage(IntTostr(list[i]));
end;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function MyFunction(
  Param1: TMyType1,       // функции передается копия переменной (только внутрь, input)
  const Param2: TMyType2, // функции передается переменная по ссылке доступная только для чтение (input)
  var Param3: TMyType3,   // функции передается переменная по ссылке доступная только для чтение и записи (input/output)
  out Param4: TMyType4    // функции передается переменная по ссылке доступная только для записи (output)
  ): TMyType5;
```

пример

```
procedure CopyTo(const From: Integer; out ATo: Integer);
begin
  ATo := From;
end;

//...

var
  I: Integer;
begin
  CopyTo(5, I);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(I));
end;
```

П. С.: В случаи создания TList (ответ выше), потом нужно очистить память (List := Func; List.Free)
И начиная с Delphi 2010 - есть дженерики (generics). 
Например в модуле Generics.Collections есть объект `TList<T>`

.
Использовать можно так:

```
var
  IntList: TList<Integer>;
begin
  IntList := TList<Integer>.Create;
  try
    IntList.Add(1235);
    WriteLn(IntList.Items[0]);
  finally
    IntList.Free;
  end;
end;
```